# Display only years in JQuery UI Calendar

Tags: jquery-ui, calendar

how can i show or display only years in JQuery UI Calendar?
I need to do a dropdown list with years without taking care the month, just years.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: true
    });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Alternatively, if you just want a list of years, you can generate it without jQueryUI:

```
var i,yr,now = new Date();
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    yr = now.getFullYear()+i; // or whatever
    $('#select-year').append($('<option/>').val(yr).text(yr));
};
```

Comment: Well, of course it does -- it's a *monthly calendar*, you need *some* indication of what month you're on. Are you expecting a calendar for all twelve months? or just a dropdown of years? You need to explain yourself better.

Comment: I think your first approuch was better than this answer. As i said, i need a dropdown list with years, i mean, just a dropdown of years :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a jquery UI datepicker which shows only the year, try this:

```
stepMonths: 12,
monthNames: ["","","","","","","","","","","",""]
```

Result: no month name is shown.

I also used this to hide the calendar-part of the datepicker:

```
<style>.ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none; } </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i,yr,now = new Date();

for (i=0; i<10; i++) {

    yr = now.getFullYear()+i; // or whatever
    $('#select-year').append($('<option/>').val(yr).text(yr));

};
```

This function works very well but it has some error

1. It display year 3 times.
2. When we select second time the data display with previous selected data.