# jQuery UI DatePicker - How to show only year (Yearpicker)?

Tags: jquery

jQuery UI DatePicker

How to show only year (Yearpicker)? Similar to calendar on windows 7

I use function: onChangeMonthYear but it's not working

Please see the picture:

http://i768.photobucket.com/albums/xx330/nnt25251325/yearpicker_zps49p4jfbz.png

or:

https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/1517517_673249596145343_3722024474719686511_n.jpg?oh=7dbe1d315c414000420aeb41d7462f78&oe=56309A3C

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display only years in JQuery UI Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521405/display-only-years-in-jquery-ui-calendar)

Comment: I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```